# regular expression question (python)

Tags: python, regex

I want to read a word html file and grab any words which contain letters of a name but not print them if the words are longer than the name

```
# compiling the regular expression:
keyword = re.compile(r"^[(rR)|(yY)|(aA)|(nN)]{5}$/")

if keyword.search (line):
    print line,
```

i am grabbing the words with this but don't seem to be limiting the size properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems you are looking for `keyword.match()` instead of `keyword.search()`. you should read [this part of the python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#matching-vs-searching) which discusses the difference between match and search.

also, your regular expression seems completely off... `[` and `]` delimits a set of characters, so you can't put groups and have a logic around the groups. as written, your expression will also match all `(`, `)` and `|`. you may try the following:

```
keyword = re.compile(r"^[rRyYaAnN]{5}$")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your RE `"^[(rR)|(yY)|(aA)|(nN)]{5}$/"` will never never never give a matching in any string on earth and elsewhere, I think, because of the `'/'` character after `'$'`

See the results of the RE without this `'/'`:

```
import re

pat = re.compile("^[(rR)|(yY)|(aA)|(nN)]{5}$")

for ch in ('arrrN','Aar)N','()|Ny','NNNNN',
           'marrrN','12Aar)NUUU','NNNNN!'):
    print ch.ljust(15),pat.search(ch)
```

result

```
arrrN           <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x011C8EC8>
Aar)N           <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x011C8EC8>
()|Ny           <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x011C8EC8>
NNNNN           <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x011C8EC8>
marrrN          None
12Aar)NUUU      None
NNNNN!          None
```

My advice: think of `[.....]` in a RE  as representing ONE character at ONE position. So every character that is between the brackets is one of the options of represented character.

Moreover, as said by Adrien Plisson, between brackets `[......]` a lot of special characters lost their speciality. Hence `'('`, `')'`,`'|'` don't define group and OR, they represent just these characters as some of the options along with the letters `'aArRyYnN'`

.

`"^[rRyYaAnN]{1,5}$"`  will match only strings as 'r',ar','YNa','YYnA','Nanny'

If you want to match the same words anywhere in a text, you will need `"[rRyYaAnN]{1,5}"`